# How to tell sed "dot match new line"?

Tags: sed

I can't figure how to tell sed to [dot match new line](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch06_07.htm):

`echo -e "one\ntwo\nthree" | sed 's/one.*two/one/m'`

I expect to get:

> one
> three

instead I get the original:

> one
> two
> three

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sed` is line-based tool. I don't think these is an option.
You can use `h/H`(hold), `g/G`(get).

```
$ echo -e 'one\ntwo\nthree' | sed -n '1h;1!H;${g;s/one.*two/one/p}'
one
three
```

Maybe you should try `vim`

```
:%s/one\_.*two/one/g
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I don't feel comfortable in `vim` (I'm new Linux user) AFAIK operator m/M is used to tell `sed` to switch to multiline mode

Comment: I just saw your edited solution. Seems to cryptic but it's correct answer I guess. Thanks

Comment: @zetah `Hold` everything to `hold-space`, then `get` it, and do the substitution.

Answer (score 5):

If you use a GNU `sed`, you may match *any* character, including line break chars, with a mere `.`, see :

> `.`
>            *Matches any character, including newline.*

All you need to use is a [`-z` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Command_002dLine-Options.html#index-_002dz):

```
echo -e "one\ntwo\nthree" | sed -z 's/one.*two/one/'
# => one
#    three
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/MCzU0i).

**However**, `one.*two` might not be what you need since `*` is always greedy in POSIX regex patterns. So, `one.*two` will match the leftmost `one`, then any 0 or more chars as many as possible, and then the rightmost `two`. If you need to remove `one`, then any 0+ chars as *few* as possible, and then the leftmost `two`, you will have to use `perl`:

```
perl -i -0 -pe 's/one.*?two//sg' file             # Non-Unicode version
perl -i -CSD -Mutf8 -0 -pe 's/one.*?two//sg' file # S&R in a UTF8 file
```

The `-0` option enables the [*slurp mode*](http://slurp%20mode) so that the file could be read as a whole and not line-by-line, `-i` will enable inline file modification, `s` will make `.` match any char including line break chars, and `.*?` will match any 0 or more chars as few as possible due to a non-greedy `*?`. The `-CSD -Mutf8` part make sure your input is decoded and output re-encoded back correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use python this way:

```
$ echo -e "one\ntwo\nthree" | python -c 'import re, sys; s=sys.stdin.read(); s=re.sub("(?s)one.*two", "one", s); print s,'
one
three
$
```

This reads the entire python's standard input (`sys.stdin.read()`), then substitutes "one" for "one.*two" with [dot matches all setting enabled](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) (using `(?s)` at the start of the regular expression) and then prints the modified string (the trailing comma in print is used to prevent print from adding an extra newline).

Comment: Excellent, great advice, will save me from future troubles. I miss easy multiline patterns, which I was used to in RegexBuddy on Windows, and then similarly easy re module in Python that I'll search for some more general code on ActiveState and make it available as system command. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
<<<$'one\ntwo\nthree' sed '/two/d'
```

or

```
<<<$'one\ntwo\nthree' sed '2d'
```

or

```
<<<$'one\ntwo\nthree' sed 'n;d'
```

or

```
<<<$'one\ntwo\nthree' sed 'N;N;s/two.//'
```

`Sed` **does** match all characters (including the `\n`) using a dot `.` but usually it has already stripped the `\n` off, as part of the cycle, so it no longer present in the pattern space to be matched.

Only certain commands (`N`,`H` and `G`) preserve newlines in the pattern/hold space.

1. `N` appends a newline to the pattern space and then appends the next line.
2. `H` does exactly the same except it acts on the hold space.
3. `G` appends a newline to the pattern space and then appends whatever is in the hold space too.

The hold space is empty until you place something in it so:

```
sed G file
```

will insert an empty line after each line.

```
sed 'G;G' file
```

will insert 2 empty lines etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

How about two sed calls: 
(get rid of the 'two' first, then get rid of the blank line)

```
$ echo -e 'one\ntwo\nthree' | sed 's/two//' | sed '/^$/d'
one
three
```

Actually, I prefer Perl for one-liners over Python:

```
$ echo -e 'one\ntwo\nthree' | perl -pe 's/two\n//'
one
three
```

Answer (score 0):

Below discussion is based on Gnu sed.

sed operates on a line by line manner. So it's not possible to tell it **dot match newline**. However, there are some tricks that can implement this. You can use a loop structure (kind of) to put all the text in the pattern space, and then do the operation.

To put everything in the pattern space, use:

```
:a;N;$!ba;
```

To make "dot match newline" indirectly, you use:

```
(\n|.)
```

So the result is:

```
root@u1804:~# echo -e "one\ntwo\nthree" | sed -r ':a;N;$!ba;s/one(\n|.)*two/one/'
one
three
root@u1804:~#
```

Note that in this case, `(\n|.)` matches newline and all characters. See below example:

```
root@u1804:~# echo -e "oneXXXXXX\nXXXXXXtwo\nthree" | sed -r ':a;N;$!ba;s/one(\n|.)*two/one/'
one
three
root@u1804:~#
```

Answer (score 0):

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182153/sed-read-whole-file-into-pattern-space-without-failing-on-single-line-input/182154#182154

Use `H;1h;\\\$!d;x; ...` as prefix to portable load whole stream into pattern space.

The `:a;N;$!ba;` can not parse text consisted of a single line.

The `:a;$!{N;ba};` can, but not portable.