# sed substitute does not quite work as expected

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I am executing a shell script where i should replace string in a file. So of course i am using `sed` for that. The string is something like:

```
<!--replace-->
<script src="1.js"></script>
<script src="2.js"></script>
<!--/replace-->
```

This should be replaced with:

```
<script src="3.js"></script>
```

So i am trying to do it as follows:

```
$ sed "s/<\!--replace-->.\*<\!--\/replace-->/<script src=\"3.js\"><\/script>/g" file.html
```

But this does not do the trick. What am i missing?

UPD: Removing `\n` from file is not a solution in this case, simply because file should be readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to newlines, you can change your regex to match newlines, or remove newlines
using `tr` :

```
user@machine:/tmp$ cat s.txt 

<!--replace-->
<script src="1.js"></script>
<script src="2.js"></script>
<!--/replace-->

user@machine:/tmp$ tr "\n" " " < s.txt | sed "s#<\!--replace-->.*<\!--/replace-->#<script src="3.js"></script>#g" 

<script src=3.js></script>
```

In case you do not want to remove the newlines, you can :

a) Try a solution using SED as mentioned here:
[how to tell sed "dot match new line"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624283/how-to-tell-sed-dot-match-new-line)

b) use perl or python  to replace the multiline regex,with `s` modifier , the newlines will be intact :

```
user@mmmm:/tmp$ cat s.txt 

<!--replace-->
<script src="1.js"></script>
<script src="2.js"></script>
<!--/replace-->

Dummy content containing
newlines for test.

user@mmmm:/tmp$ perl -i -pe 'BEGIN{undef $/;} s#<\!--replace-->.*<\!--/replace-->#<script src="3.js"></script>#gsm' s.txt 

user@mmmm:/tmp$ cat s.txt 

<script src="3.js"></script>

Dummy content containing
newlines for test.
```

Comment: I should not remove newlines from file, hence this way is not the one i need. Also AFAIK `.\*` should match all chars including new lines. Is that right?  If not, how would i change expression to match newlines?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of doing it: deleting (`d`) all lines starting from the line containing `<!--replace-->` to the line containing `<!--\replace-->`. But for the first line of the block, insert (`i`) the replacement line before deleting.

```
sed '/<!--replace-->/,/<!--\/replace-->/ {
         /<!--replace-->/ i\<script src="3.js"></script>
         d      
     }' file
```

---

Another way is appending the whole block in the pattern space then replacing the pattern space (i.e. replacing the whole block) with the replacement line.

```
sed '/<!--replace-->/ {
         :loop
         N
         /<!--\/replace-->/ ! b loop
         c\<script src="3.js"></script>
     }' file
```

**Details**:

1. If the line contains `<!--replace-->`, go into `{..}`
2. `:loop` is a label (it is a marker that you can go to)
3. `N` goes to next line and appends the next line to the pattern space.
4. If the line does not contain `<!--/replace-->`, then go (`b`ranch) to the label `loop`
5. Repeat 3-4 until line contains `<!--/replace-->`. At this point, replace (`c`hange) the pattern space with the replacement line.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/<!--replace-->/!b;:a;$!{N;/<!--\/replace-->/!ba};c\<script src="3.js"></script>' file
```

Answer (score 0):

if syntax is correct but the / delimiter is part of your word
E.g -  `sed 's/test/1/replace/value/g' file.txt`
then we can change  delimiter with +
E.g `sed 's+test/1+replace/value+g' file.txt`

Now the question is if + and / delimiter is also part of your word

E.g `sed 's+test/1+replace++/value+g' file.txt`

in that case you can also use - delimiter
For E.g `sed 's-test/1-replace++/value-g' file.txt`

it works for me

Thankyou